# acts-as-taggable-on(2.2.2) will_paginate(3.0.2) rails(3.0.3) ruby 1.8.7 tagged_with method undefined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, will-paginate, acts-as-taggable-on

Am using below specified gem

```
acts-as-taggable-on(2.2.2)
will_paginate(3.0.2)
rails(3.0.3) 
ruby 1.8.7
```

i tried to use tagged_with undefined method tagged_with
Code

```
@search = Product.tagged_with(params[:search][:tag_name]).paginate(:per_page => 15, :page => params[:page])
```

Output:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `tagged_with' for #<Class:0xb51a0f08>):
```

than i tried find_tagged_with undefined method paginate
Code

```
@search = Product.find_tagged_with(params[:search][:tag_name]).paginate(:per_page => 15, :page => params[:page])
```

Output

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `paginate' for #<Array:0xb512f790>):


class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :tag_list
  acts_as_taggable
end
```

Kindly either Guide me way to make Will_paginate to work with Array/acts-as-taggable-on.
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this line in the file you are using `will_paginate` over arrays.

```
require 'will_paginate/array'
```

If you want it globally enabled, add it to end of `application.rb`

Comment: Restarting the Rails server may fix the problem.